# AnyLogic - Java actions

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I got the problem with inicalize variable.
The parametrs `palletRack1`, `palletRack` and `noliktava` is defined in `Main`, 
when I use the root. , have message **root cannot be resolved**.

Anylogic in Simulation:Main -> Java actions ->Initial experiment setup:
used agent and root always say **"cannot be resolved"**

```
root.palletRack1.setNumberOfPositions(root.noliktava*2); root.palletRack.setNumberOfPositions(root.noliktava*3);
```

I need to change `palletRack` number of deep position values from the **Simulation:Main**

Comment: Put your code please

Comment: There is code: palletRack1.setNumberOfPositions(noliktava*2); palletRack.setNumberOfPositions(noliktava*3);

Comment: Ok but it doesn't say anything. Put a code which shows what is palletRack and root

Comment: I try change palletRack number of deep position from Initial experiment setup with value of parameter (noliktava)

Comment: The code is to long, can I send it private?

Comment: Put here the most important things because nobody can help you now

Comment: https://failiem.lv/u/kp7zqk48 There is all AnyLogic project

Comment: Just add code of your main class where you create palletRack and noliktava variables and root

Comment: public Main( int forkliftTruck, int workers, int paletes, int noliktava ) {
    markParametersAreSet();
    this.forkliftTruck = forkliftTruck;
    this.workers = workers;
    this.paletes = paletes;
    this.noliktava = noliktava;
  }

Comment: palletRack1 = new PalletRack(this, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, 760.0, 90.0, 0.0, 160.0, 14.0, 14.0, 10.0, 0.0, PALLET_RACK_TWO_PALLET_RACKS, PALLET_RACK_NO_DIRECTION,
            11.0, 40.0, 16.0, 10, 2, 1, cyan, maroon, 100 );

    palletRack = new PalletRack(this, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, 760.0, 240.0, 0.0, 160.0, 14.0, 14.0, 10.0, 0.0, PALLET_RACK_TWO_PALLET_RACKS, PALLET_RACK_NO_DIRECTION,
            11.0, 40.0, 16.0, 10, 3, 2, cyan, maroon, 100 );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as easy as you think.. you have to do the following:

1) remove the pallet racks you currently have in your model

It will now look like this:
[image]

2) add 2 parameters in Main called palletRack and palletRack1... both of type PalletRack
[image]

3) Generate your code not in initial experiment setup, but on "before simulation run" 
[image]

This is the code:

```
PalletRack palletRack1 = new PalletRack(root, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, 760.0, 90.0, 0.0, 160.0, 14.0, 14.0, 10.0, 0.0, PALLET_RACK_TWO_PALLET_RACKS, PALLET_RACK_NO_DIRECTION,
            11.0, 40.0, 16.0, 10, 2, 1, cyan, maroon, 100 );

PalletRack palletRack = new PalletRack(root, SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, 760.0, 240.0, 0.0, 160.0, 14.0, 14.0, 10.0, 0.0, PALLET_RACK_TWO_PALLET_RACKS, PALLET_RACK_NO_DIRECTION,
            11.0, 40.0, 16.0, 10, 3, 2, cyan, maroon, 100 );

root.set_palletRack(palletRack);
root.set_palletRack1(palletRack1);

root.network.add(root.palletRack);
root.network.add(root.palletRack1);
```

You will have to check the help documentation to check what are the parameters of the PalletRack constructor:

https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2Fmarkup%2FPalletRack.html&resultof=%22PalletRack%22%20%22palletrack%22%20

Because it seems to me that the parameters you are using are wrong.. you are trying to put more positions than what the size of the palletRack allows, so it won't work at all... So you have to be careful to define everthing in the beginning effectively.

4) In main On Startup action:

```
presentation.add( palletRack);
presentation.add( palletRack1);
```